# custom datatype using implicit operator not working with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have created a custom datatype using implicit operator below is the sample code.
When I am setting hard coded value to my custom data type its working as expected, but setting value using reflection throwing conversion error. 
(System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'TF.DataType.TFDiplay'.')

Can someone help me what I need to change to work this with reflections well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TF.DataType
{
    public class TFDiplay 
    {
        public TFDiplay() { }
        public TFDiplay(object value, string text) { Value = value; Text = text; }
        public TFDiplay(object value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public static implicit operator TFDiplay(string value)
        {
            var result = new TFDiplay()
            {
                Value = value
            };
            return result;
        }

        public static implicit operator TFDiplay(int value)
        {
            var result = new TFDiplay()
            {
                Value = value
            };
            return result;
        }


        public object Value { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }


    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TFDiplay tFDiplay;

        tFDiplay = "ss"; //Working as expected
        tFDiplay = 1; //Working as expected

        testDatatype t = new testDatatype();

        Type s = t.GetType();

        PropertyInfo p = s.GetProperty("Flag");

        p.SetValue(t, "ss");  //Throwing error



    }

    public class testDatatype
    {
        public TFDiplay Flag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? that the `implicit operator` is called by magic? It's _syntactic_ sugar. If you want te set the `Text` property of `TFDiplay` which is a property of `testDatatype`. You need to use a `GetProperty("Text")` on the `Flag` property as well

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, what do you mean by "GetProperty"? I am setting the value first using this line of code PropertyInfo p = s.GetProperty("Flag"); then setting the value, please clarify if you mean to say something else.

Comment: Can you consider using a Binder? The reflection code will not be the same, you need to call another overload, but it will still be reflection. Others however, when trying to set `Flag` to a string without the correct `Binder` will still fail. But, who will try to set a reference type instance by providing a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot assign a string to a TFDiplay type via reflection. Reflection doesn't use implicit convertors. implicit convertors are compiletype. reflection is runtime.

Highlight:

```
TFDiplay tFDiplay;

tFDiplay = "ss"; //Working as expected
tFDiplay = 1; //Working as expected
```

The implicit operators does the work for you. Every time a string or an int is assigned to tFDiplay the operator is called, a new TFDisplay is initiated. So calling an operator on an existing object is useless.

This is also the reason why you don't have to initiate a new instance when you assign it.

Here is the reflection code that works:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TFDiplay tFDiplay;

            tFDiplay = "ss"; //Working as expected
            tFDiplay = 1; //Working as expected

            // ----

            // create an instance of testDatatype
            testDatatype testDatatype = new testDatatype();

            Type testDatatypeType = testDatatype.GetType();

            PropertyInfo flagProperty = testDatatypeType.GetProperty("Flag");

            // you need to get the value of the flag..
            var flagInstance = flagProperty.GetValue(testDatatype);

            Type flagType = flagInstance.GetType();

            PropertyInfo valueProperty = flagType.GetProperty("Value");

            valueProperty.SetValue(flagInstance, "ss");  
        }
    }

    public class testDatatype
    {
        // notice that I create an instance here:
        public TFDiplay Flag { get; } = new TFDiplay();
    }

    public class TFDiplay
    {
        public TFDiplay() { }
        public TFDiplay(object value, string text) { Value = value; Text = text; }
        public TFDiplay(object value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public static implicit operator TFDiplay(string value)
        {
            var result = new TFDiplay()
            {
                Value = value
            };
            return result;
        }

        public static implicit operator TFDiplay(int value)
        {
            var result = new TFDiplay()
            {
                Value = value
            };
            return result;
        }


        public object Value { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JeroenvanLangen

Answer (score 1):

And here is another approach, using a custom `Binder` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.binder?view=netframework-4.8)

I doubt that this is what you are looking for but still, it may help. Here we are just implementing the ChangeType override.

```
public class TFDisplayBinder : Binder
{
    public override object ChangeType(object value, Type type, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return (TFDiplay)(string)value;
        }
        if (value is int)
        {
            return (TFDiplay)(int)value;
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override FieldInfo BindToField(BindingFlags bindingAttr, FieldInfo[] match, object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Type.DefaultBinder.BindToField(bindingAttr, match, value, culture);
    }

    // You can implement the other abstract methods the same way, or just throw
    // NotImplementedException for they are not invoked in our case
}
```

And when assigning via reflection:

```
    testDatatype t = new testDatatype();

    Type s = t.GetType();

    PropertyInfo p = s.GetProperty("Flag");

    p.SetValue(t, "ss", BindingFlags.Default, new TFDisplayBinder(), null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @Oguz, I was looking for other way around, your solution will help me in some other scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Jeroen's answer:

Implicit operator generates a special method called `op_Implicit`. To correctly "cast" using implicit operator, you could call that method using reflection:

```
var op = typeof(TFDiplay).GetMethod("op_Implicit", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, 
    null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
tFDiplay = (TFDiplay)op.Invoke(null, new object[] { "ss" });
```

Comment: The only thing is, that it will construct a new TFDiplay instance.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen But when you do .Flag = "ss" manually, which is what the OP is trying to achieve using reflection, it also constructs a new instance.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I bet he missed that.